# Run QuerySet Django without for

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have a query in Django, and I want to apply a match in each register.

```
    whatever = Whatever.objects.all()

    for w in whatever:
        contador+=getMycoincidenceswhatever(w)
```

getMycoincidenceswhatever is a function where I search some coincidences with other table.

```
    def getMycoincidenceswhatever(w)

         coincidences=Notificationwhatever.objects.filter
         (Q(field_whatever__in=w.field)).count()
         return coincidences
```

Is there some way to do it without use bucle for? The problem is that this query is is slowing down my server, because this bucle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with a subquery:

```
from django.db.models import Subquery, Q


Notificationwhatever.objects.filter(
  field_whatever__in=Subquery(Whatever.objects.all().values("field"))
).count()
```